# How to show Xml child element name with XDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

Hello I want to show the name of child of root node using linq and xdocument but did not find any thing for the same convenient. My xml is given below

```
<temp>
<Movies>
    <Title>Man Of Steel</Title>
    <Title>Kung Fu Panda</Title>
    <Title>Thor</Title>
</Movies>
<Cars>
    <Title>Racing</Title>
    <Title>Vintage</Title>
    <Title>Luxary</Title>
</Cars>
</temp>
```

Expected out put is :

1. Movies
2. Cars

Can you please assist me. One more thing I want this to be done dynamically that means from code I don't want to place the name of element. This is to be done with something

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Folder.xml");
var element = xdoc.Root.Elements();
foreach(var a in element)
{
   Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
}
```

This code is working in console application but when I am trying to implement this in wpf application to create radiobutton for these category this code shows nothing there. It shows blank. That's why I was facing problem.

Comment: Your code already displays Movies and Cars which is the expected output. I don't quite understand what your problem is..

Comment: Recheck the output its working perfectly what else you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
foreach(var a in element)
{
    RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
    rdb.content = a.Name.LocalName;
}
```

I hope this might help.

Comment: Ahh! I was making the mistake for adding LocalName. Now it's working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if you're actually wish to list all movies and cars items than use the following code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Folder.xml");
if (xdoc.Root != null)
{
    var element = xdoc.Root.Elements();
    foreach (var a in element)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
        foreach (var item in a.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
Movies
        Man Of Steel
        Kung Fu Panda
        Thor
Cars
        Racing
        Vintage
        Luxary
```